# Print FixedDocument onto label without PrintDialog (setting page margin and size myself)

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

tl;dr: Why do I need to set an extra "magic" offset on the left side when printing with WPF, XpsDocumentWriter and FixedDocument compared to printing with WinForms and PrintDocument?

---

I am building a WPF app that creates a FixedDocument and prints it to a label printer via XpsDocumentWriter. It's split in two parts, as I want the printer part to be able to receive and print a FixedDocument over the network from another app.

It's for use with a point of sale system, so I do not want to show a PrintDialog for every print. Size of labels and the printer name is stored in a template file. The things to be printed is in the template file combined with some data. (In below example printer name is taken from a combobox for now and just some demo things to be printed).

I retrieve the printer queue with the given printer name, and I can print to the printer, but the margins are quite off - the print is too far to the left, outside of the label and by more than just the liner margin (distance from label edge to the roll edge). By trial'n'error I found the magic offset to be around 20 plus the liner margin, but I guess that's different on another printer.

The old version of this app (which is made with WinForms and PrintDocument) prints allright (no matter how the printer properties' paper is setup). The wish from business is that all setup is in the template file, completely disregarding printer properties setup. That is how it is functioning now in the WinForms app.

- What am I forgetting to set, what's the gotchas?
- Should I do it some other way?
- Do I need to set the PageMediaSize and PageMediaType, and why?
- I'd like to do checks on PrinterCapabilities, but not if they depend on the current printer properties like the page size set in the properties. That one I'd like to set in code.

**Update 11/3**
I now tried printing to both a Metapace and a Zebra labelprinter, and both is happy with the 20 unit offset on the left side. But... why is it needed? When printing to pdf/xps, I get the offset to the left plus the margin on both sides. This I do not get with the old program in Winforms?

And do I need to do Measure, Arrange and UpdateLayout?

**Part one - the FixedDocument creator**

```
var printerName = CmbPrinters.SelectedValue.ToString();
var size =
    (FlexTemplate.TemplateParser.TemplateFunctions.Size)
        template.Functions.First(f => f is FlexTemplate.TemplateParser.TemplateFunctions.Size);
var labelSize = new Size(size.Width.Value, size.Height.Value);

// Dimensions are 1/96th of an inch, socalled Device Independent Pixels (matches 96 DPI, which is normal?)
var linerMargin = 4.7244094488189;  // 1.25 mm
var magicOffset = 20;               // 5.29 mm

// The document

var doc = new FixedDocument();
doc.PrintTicket = new PrintTicket();
var printTicket = (PrintTicket) doc.PrintTicket;
printTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.Unknown, size.Width.Value, size.Height.Value);

// New page

var page = new FixedPage
{
    Width = labelSize.Width + magicOffset + 2 * linerMargin,
    Height = labelSize.Height,
    Margin = new Thickness(magicOffset + linerMargin, 0, linerMargin, 0)
};

// Page content

var border = new Border
{
    Width = labelSize.Width,
    Height = labelSize.Height,
    BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(4)
};

FixedPage.SetLeft(border, 0);
FixedPage.SetTop(border, 0);
page.Children.Add(border);

// Next item on page

var tb = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "Hello World!",
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Algerian Regular"),
    FontSize = 30,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
};

var content = new Border
{
    Child = tb,
    BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1)
};

FixedPage.SetLeft(content, 10);
FixedPage.SetTop(content, 10);
page.Children.Add(content);

// Next item on page

var tb2 = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "SomethingElse",
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI"),
    FontSize = 20,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
};

var content2 = new Border
{
    Child = tb2,
    BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1)
};

FixedPage.SetLeft(content2, 20);
FixedPage.SetTop(content2, 55);
page.Children.Add(content2);

//// Add the page to the document

//var pc = new PageContent();     // Old way of doing it (.NET 3.5 and earlier)
//((IAddChild)pc).AddChild(page); //
//doc.Pages.Add(pc);              //

var pc = new PageContent();
pc.Child = page;
doc.Pages.Add(pc);

// Send it to the printer   

FlexPrinter.Print(printerName, labelSize, doc);
```

**Part two - the FixedDocument printer**

```
// Get XpsDocumentWriter
PrintQueue queue = new PrintServer().GetPrintQueue(printerName);

var dw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
dw.Write(document);
```